# C#- Getting last id from a table in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table in sqlite that contains many columns like id,number,name 
id is primary and auto increment , when i try to get the last id inserted in The table "Data" it returns "-1"

The connection :

```
 SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Datasource =|DataDirectory|\SmartScale.db");
```

The code i use :

```
        con.Open();
       SQLiteCommand cmd=new SQLiteCommand("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Data", con);
       int id= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        tId.Text =Convert.ToString(id);
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for that, `ExecuteScalar` is more appropriate because it gives you the first column of the first row in the result set.

When using `ExecuteNonQuery`, the `-1` is what you always get for select statements. For inserts, updates or deletes the return value is the number of rows affected by the statement.